# What is under app/src/main/res/mipmap-* during Android development?

Tags: android, resources, android-drawable

I see in the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html, that all types of drawable resources are located under `.../res/drawable`.

Neither drawable resource is under `.../res/mipmap-*`.

So, does this mean that `.../res/mipmap-*` doesn't contain any drawables? If I create image file, scale it to various sizes and put into `.../res/mipmap-*`, the same way as `ic_launcher` lays, will I be able to refer this resource from XMLs as drawable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, does this mean that .../res/mipmap-* doesn't contain any drawables?

It contains bitmaps, mostly of [launcher icons](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskProvideAltBmp).

> will I be able to refer this resource from XMLs as drawable?

No, but you will be able to refer to that resource as a mipmap (`@mipmap/ic_launcher`), the same way that you see in the manifest for launcher icons.